# For loop qustion javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to do a for loop that is looping 50 times but I need the code block inside the loop to run just on multiples of nine(9,18,27,36..)
How can I do it?

Comment: Show us what you tried for your basic homework assignment. I am sure your teacher/professor taught you about the Modulus Operator.

Comment: what do u know about for loops? what exactly do u want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (i % 9 == 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/LBJve/)

```
for(var i = 0; i < 450; i += 9) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/LBJve/2/)

Comment: beware that `console` is undefined in IE unless F12 tool is open, also `console.log` doesn't exist in IE8

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i=0; i<450; i+=9) {
   ...
}
```

Alternatively, for better readability:

```
for(var nines = 0, loop_counter=0; loop_counter<50; loop_counter += 1, nines = loop_counter*9) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Haha, that's a subjective "better" ;)

Comment: Ofcourse, it is subjective. It's also obvious that this is some basic course assingment so I wanted to show him that he can instantiate (modify) more than one variable in a for loop as might be useful sometimes - although I admit that I used it maybe 3 or 4 times during 10 years in all languages I used... :) [edit] Oh! Including this answer that's five :P

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (i % 9 == 0) {
        //code block here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; ++i) {
  (function(multipleOfNine) {
    // Do something with multipleOfNine
  }(i * 9));
}
```

I interpreted your question to mean you want to loop over the first 50 multiples of nine. If what you meant was you want just the multiples of nine under 50, then use [EnterSB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19275083/105570).

Comment: Thats bit too complicated for a school assignment probably :P

Comment: @aliasm2k: Yeah, yeah... but maybe now he'll ask "Why would I use this pattern?" and learn something new ;)

Comment: Why would he use that pattern? ;)

Comment: @Kyra: To address the [infamous loop problem](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Comment: @DanTao That's a very good post about closures and scopes, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score -1):

Record which iteration of the loop you are in (simplest way is to initialize a variable outside the loop to 0 and then increment it every time you go through the loop) and then use Modulo to check if it's divisible by 9. e.g. x=i%9. If x is 0 then i's a multiple of 9.